# Rcpparmadillo : Convert fastLM object to type 'lm'

Tags: r, rcpp

First of all thanks for such a nice package. I was looking to run anova on the output of fastLM, however anova only accepts objects of type 'lm'. Is there a way to convert a fastLM object to an 'lm' object?

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1):

First off, `fastLM()` exists to provide something faster than `lm()`.

One of the ways to make it faster is to provide a lot less information in the returned object than `lm()` does:

```
R> object.size(fitlm <- lm(Girth ~ Volume + Height, data=trees))
22960 bytes
R> library(RcppArmadillo)
R> object.size(fitFastLm <- fastLm(Girth ~ Volume + Height, data=trees))
4264 bytes
R>
```

That shows that for the (small, trivial) example from the trees data set, we return 4.2 kB whereas `lm()` returns 23kb.  Hence I chose not to subclass the returned object as being of class `lm()` -- as we don't include a full object.

So `anova()` may fail.  The easiest would probably be to factor out actual anova code and provide a suitable method as we do provide some analytics:

```
R> summary(fitFastLm <- fastLm(Girth ~ Volume + Height, data=trees))

Call:
fastLm.formula(formula = Girth ~ Volume + Height, data = trees)

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-1.342900 -0.566960 -0.086282  0.802830  1.116400 

            Estimate   StdErr t.value  p.value    
(Intercept) 10.81637  1.97320   5.482 7.45e-06 ***
Volume       0.19518  0.01096  17.816  < 2e-16 ***
Height      -0.04548  0.02826  -1.609    0.119    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.79 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.941,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.937
R>
```

If you want to work on providing anova analysis based on this, I could consider a well-written patch.