# How to get output like the one from lm() + anova() but with RcppEigen::fastLm()?

Tags: r, lm

Example:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x1 = factor(sample(1:2, 100, replace = T)))

mod1 <- lm(y ~ x1, df)
anova(mod1)
```

Output:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
x1         1  0.388 0.38766  0.3879 0.5349
Residuals 98 97.940 0.99939
```

With RcppEigen:

```
mod2 <- RcppEigen::fastLm(y = df$y, X = model.matrix(~ x1, df))
anova(mod2)
```

Error:

```
Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
  no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "fastLm"
```

Is there a way to replicate the output obtained with the base R function while using `RcppEigen::fastLm()`?

Comment: Not at my computer right now, but I'd guess that you need to write an `update` method for fastLm objects, which in turn will require a wrapper that can handle formulas

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847101/12957340

Comment: @jared_mamrot yes it does, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. There's also a chance you can get what you need from the internal summary function (`RcppEigen:::summary.fastLm(mod2)`) but obviously not an ANOVA table.